# How do I find if the array have any two elements (i+j) which is equal to my given key?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean

Let's say I am given an array

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

and I have to input a "key" value which is based on user input.

If the array have any two elements that sums up to my key value it returns a true value or otherwise a false value. Why do I still have issue with my algorithm? Is there some misconception that I am putting in the nested loop? Any help with this please?

```
public static boolean checkPair(int[] arr, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == key) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: _**You have to learn to debug your application!**_ Your code will return the first time it reaches the `if ... else` part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `else`-clause is wrong. It **always** returns `false` if the first pair hasn't the same value.

Change your code like this:

```
public static boolean checkPair(int[] arr, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
         if (arr[i] + arr[j] == key) {
           return true;
         }
        //else {      
        //  return false;    <- this returns always false if the 
        //                      first pair isnt a i,j-match
        //}
      } 
    }
    return false;  // stub
}
```

**Explanation**

In your example `int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`

`arr[i] = 1` and `a[j] = 2` If you set key to any int except 3, the method will return false and the other numbers will not be considered

Comment: Although this is correct, I think it would be helpful to say some words about how he could've found that out by himself

Comment: As @ParkerHalo already mentioned OP has to learn debugging, So I don't see any point to simply give correct code to OP

Comment: Okay I think I got what you're saying! Kinda misunderstood my own codes.

Comment: @ParkerHalo Is this better?

Comment: @ParkerHalo Yeap I am aware of what I did wrongly already and will be more careful in reading my own codes next time. Kudos to the both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this task can be solved faster than your algorithm. Are your array sorted?? If yes, you can do that:

```
public static boolean checkPair(int[] arr, int key) {
  int i = 0; //first index
  int j = arr.length - 1; //last index
  while (i < j) {
    if (arr[i] + arr[j] > key){
      j--;
      continue;
    }
    if (arr[i] + arr[j] < key){
      i++;
      continue;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If your array are not sorted, you can sort it with java standart sort and use my algorithm.
My algorithm faster more than 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think the task can be done in this way also:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public static void checkPair(int[] arr, int k) {
  HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int x = k - arr[i];
    if(s.contains(x)) {
      System.out.println(arr[i] + " " + x);
    }
    s.add(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` will not work if the target is `10` and the `array[]={ 2, 5}`
then for the `index=1` 
`rem=tar-arr[1]` i.e., `5` which is found in the `HashSet`
and you return `true` based on this condition, which is `false`.

So, we have to use the HashMap

```
public static void main(String[] args){<br>
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);<br>

    int arr[]={5,2,5};<br>
    int  tar=10;

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> fmap=new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        fmap.put(arr[i], fmap.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0)+1);
    }

    boolean f=false;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        int rem=tar-arr[i];
        if(rem==arr[i] && fmap.get(arr[i])>1){   //if arr[i]==rem
            f=true;                              //than arr[i] should be more than 1
            break;
        }else if(rem!=arr[i]){        // rem is present then we got the target pair
            if(fmap.containsKey(rem)){
            f=true;
            break;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(f);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

you just break loop like this:

```
public static boolean checkPair(int[] arr, int key) {

    boolean isMacthed = false;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == key) {
          isMacthed=true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(isMacthed) break;
    }
    return isMacthed ; 
    }
```

Comment: why would he set a variable, break out of the loop and return outside of the loop if he could just `return true` in that if case?

Comment: You can simply return true if condition satisfy

Comment: @Lokesh yes, your way is better, but this code is Simple to understanding for beginners.

Comment: @ParkerHalo I use `isMacthed` for clarify her mistake.

Comment: @amirazizkhani you should defenetly not try to teach beginners how to use `break`!